# Update number from api after an interval

Tags: jquery, setinterval

So I want to update the request to my Github page after an interval. I want to count how many commits I've done to a repo and then in the HTML count the number given from 0. I also want it to update automatically without so the user has to update the page. What happens now is that it gets a request and number and counts, I want the interval to be 10 minutes. As it is now it requests but the counting on the website should start directly not according to the interval after 5 seconds

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/95pfB/

Comment: You want the interval to be 10 mins? 5 seconds? confusing!

Comment: the interval itself is not a problem, sorry for crappy text. But I want the HTML to load when page loads, but after that I want to keep the number updated through request to github every 10 minute

Comment: turn all the code inside the setinterval function in to a function. say, function runcode. then, call runcode on doc ready. then let the setinteval call your method every 10 minutes.

Comment: can you show how you mean? @LShetty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, thank you LShetty. It worked, heres the complete code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
runCode();

    function runCode() {

    var uri = "your url to github";
    var totalCom = 0;
    $.getJSON(uri, function(r) {
        for (var i = 0; i < r[0].total; i++) {
            totalCom = r[0].total;
        }
    //count numbers from zero
    $({countNum:
        $('.row-one-first .number').text()}).animate({countNum: totalCom}, {
            duration: 5000,
            easing:'linear',
            step: function() {
            // What todo on every count
            $('.row-one-first .number').text(Math.floor(this.countNum));
            },
            complete: function() {
            $('.row-one-first .number').text(this.countNum);
            }
        });
    })
}
setInterval (function() {
    runCode();
}, 300000);
```

});